# Connection refused when using thrift nodejs to connect hbase

Tags: javascript, node.js, connection, hbase

I want to save my data in Hbase. So i wanted to connect with Nodejs and Hbase. I found a tutorial http://www.amicksolutions.com/blog/hadoop-using-nodejs-with-hbase and its working. This is following code of Hbase connection:

```
var thrift = require('thrift'),
  HBase = require('./gen-nodejs/HBase.js'),
  HBaseTypes = require('./gen-nodejs/HBase_types.js'),
  connection = thrift.createConnection('localhost', 9090, {
    transport: thrift.TBufferedTransport,
    protocol: thrift.TBinaryProtocol
  });

connection.on('connect', function() {
  var client = thrift.createClient(HBase,connection);
  client.getTableNames(function(err,data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('get table names error:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('hbase tables:', data);
    }
    connection.end();
  });
});

connection.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('error:', err);
});
```

This above code is working perfectly, i am able to list all tables but problem is i want to do CURD operations also. I have searched a lot but not found proper documentation on this module, How to do other operations like get, put.

This is another module i found https://github.com/wdavidw/node-hbase Having good documentation but i am not able to connect with this following code:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var hbase = require('hbase');

hbase({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 9090 })
.table('my_table' )
.create('my_column_family', function(err, success){
  this
  .row('my_row')
  .put('my_column_family:my_column', 'my value', function(err, success){
    this.get('my_column_family', function(err, cells){
      this.exists(function(err, exists){
        assert.ok(exists);
      });
    });
  });
})
```

This may be i have to use some protocol here also. I don't know what is catch. I am not able to connect and getting following error:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

Another confusion is https://github.com/wdavidw/node-hbase this module uses thrift API or not? Is there is any other workaround?

Comment: Look in `./gen-nodejs/HBase.js  HbaseClient.prototype.*` all CRUD interface inside.

Comment: Ohhh Yes @stdob-- i found many functions. But how to insert in HBASE? I haven't found any `put` function.

Comment: Thrift Hadoop API description: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/hbase-thrift/src/main/resources/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/Hbase.thrift?view=markup

Comment: That is completely huge i am not about to find `put` method or something like how to insert.

Comment: Ok, you need `mutateRow` (example: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/blmarket/7333706/raw/d88865fa8fac7af9062f28c3df1c587e686b3424/test.coffee)

Comment: Hmmm good catch. I have used this one and its working. Thanks @stdob--

Answer (score 2):

This is how i have done insertion:

```
try{
    var data = [];
    data.push(new Mutation({column:'data:sender','value':'2444'}));
    data.push(new Mutation({column:'data:receiver','value':'1334'}));
    data.push(new Mutation({column:'data:message','value':'HIdfgs'}));

    var client = thrift.createClient(HBase,connection);
    // console.log(client.mutateRow)
    client.mutateRow(TABLE, 'row1', data, null, function(error, success){
        console.log("INsertklsd")
    })
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error trying to connect with [node-hbase](https://github.com/adaltas/node-hbase):

```
{ 
    [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect' 
}
```

My solution was based on [hbase.apache.org book, chapter: REST](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_rest). On your hbase server in hbase directory (which for me is `/usr/local/hbase/`, just for better overview), I ran:

```
./bin/hbase rest start -p 8080
```

It starts REST server, port `8080` is the default one, adjust it for your needs. 
After that, running the **code from node-hbase documentation**:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var hbase = require('hbase');

hbase({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 8080})
.table('my_table' )
.create('my_column_family', function(err, success){
  this
  .row('my_row')
  .put('my_column_family:my_column', 'my value', function(err, success){
    this.get('my_column_family', function(err, cells){
      this.exists(function(err, exists){
        assert.ok(exists);
      });
    });
  });
})
```

worked as expected.